# val_loss too high and val_categorical_accuracy is zero

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, prediction, tf.keras

I tying to predict Diabetic Retiopathy.
I have 6000 training dataset separate in  class 0:3647 class 1:750   class 2:1105 class 3:305 class 4:193
and I have 1000 validate dataset separate in class 0:427 class 1:142 class 2:202 class 3:148 class 4:81

I use imagedatagenerator for augmentation

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    rotation_range=40,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest',
    preprocessing_function=HE,
)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255
)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255
)

#get image and label with augmentation
train = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
'train/train_deep/',
target_size=(224,224),
class_mode='categorical',
shuffle=False,
batch_size = 20,
)

test = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'test_deep/',
    batch_size=1,
    class_mode=None,
    shuffle=False,
    target_size = (224,224),

)

val = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'train/validate_deep/',
    target_size=(224,224),
    batch_size = 1,
    shuffle=False,
    class_mode='categorical'
)
```

I compute a weight for fit_generator using sklearn and using model densenet121

```
history = model.fit_generator(
    train,
    epochs=Epoch,
    steps_per_epoch=int(6000/32),
    class_weight=class_weight,
    validation_data=val,
    validation_steps=int(1000/32),
    use_multiprocessing = False,
    max_queue_size=100,
    workers = 16,
    callbacks=callbacks_list
)
```

but when I train they show a strange value of val_loss

```
Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 11363.97366, saving model to weight/weights-improvement-01-11363.97.hdf5

187/187 [==============================] - 203s 1s/step - loss: 2.0711 - categorical_accuracy: 0.1313 - val_loss: 11363.9737 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

I don't know why they are high from loss value a lot.
in 50 epoch

```
Epoch 00050: val_loss did not improve from 0.00000

187/187 [==============================] - 802s 4s/step - loss: 1.6423 - categorical_accuracy: 0.4567 - val_loss: 795.2247 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

when I print a confusion matrix of validate data ,it shows many wrong predict

```
Confusion Matrix
[[  0   0   5 422   0]
 [  0   0   5 137   0]
 [  0   0   4 198   0]
 [  0   0   6 142   0]
 [  0   0   1  80   0]]
 precision    recall  f1-score   support

           No DR       0.00      0.00      0.00       427
            Mild       0.00      0.00      0.00       142
        Moderate       0.19      0.02      0.04       202
          Severe       0.15      0.96      0.25       148
Proliferative DR       0.00      0.00      0.00        81

        accuracy                           0.15      1000
       macro avg       0.07      0.20      0.06      1000
    weighted avg       0.06      0.15      0.04      1000
```

and I predic a test dataset , I have 25 test dataset for small predict but it show all are 3

```
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
```

**Problem**
1.why val_loss too high a lot from loss and what should I do?
2.If I want a good prediction should I increase epoch for more training or anything?

this is accuracy and loss in 30 epoch
[acc in 30 epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPTN3.png)
[loss in 30 epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRuh1.png)
and this is accuracy and loss in 50 epoch
[acc in 50 epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Amfa.png)
[loss in 50 epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M0B6.png)

Comment: can you provide the full history? my suspicion is that your model is not good, secondly you should change steps per epoch and validation steps to 6000/20 and 1000/1 respectively.

Comment: alslo you should use shuffle True for train data

Comment: Thank you for your advice,I will change and test it again

Comment: I use a densenet model `
model = tf.compat.v1.keras.applications.DenseNet121(include_top=True, weights=None, input_tensor=None, input_shape=(224,224,3), pooling=None, classes=5)  
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])`

Comment: And I have a callback for reduce learning rate
`checkpointer = tf.compat.v1.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath,monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,save_weights_only=True)
lr_reduction =  tf.compat.v1.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, verbose=2, factor=0.1,cooldown=1)
`

Comment: I change epoch to 30 for fast train and it not help val_loss to high same
`Epoch 00030: val_loss did not improve from 44.93120

300/300 [==============================] - 680s 2s/step - loss: 1.5565 - categorical_accuracy: 0.2448 - val_loss: 10329.9246 - val_categorical_accuracy: 0.4270`

Comment: and confusion matrix really bad from before (50 epoch)
`Confusion Matrix
[[427   0   0   0   0]
 [142   0   0   0   0]
 [202   0   0   0   0]
 [148   0   0   0   0]
 [ 81   0   0   0   0]]
`